# Existing Entity gets update when update entity data modal from database after create new table, how to stop it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Actually I am new in entity frame work so I have table called AllUsers and when I have updated entity modal it create entity called "AllUsers" entity in modal, then I have added new property into this entity, and then when I create new table in database and again update entity data modal, with newly created table then my "AllUsers" entity get updated and extra added properties deleted. so how can I stop to update modified entities.

Comment: can you elaborate what do you want?

Comment: See, when I add [display name ]attribute in X entity and then create new table in database and update my entity data modal with newly created table then my X entity [display name] gets deleted. so how to stop or other way to have entity with new tables in entity modal.

Comment: ok, so what I am understanding is that.. You want that your [display name] attributes don't get deleted when you update your model?? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly and also extra added entities like, I have add IEnumerable   list of any other class.

Comment: have you tried my answer??

Comment: thank you, how can i use meta data, can you give me the link where I can refer, i didn't found any appropriate link to learn how to metadata.

Comment: I have mentioned some code in my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Manually Define the Model and Mapping Files for that specific table
for more details check below link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb399785(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thank you, but is there not other way to do it.. because its not seems like simple and for huge data base its not feasible to do..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a MetaData Class and define all of your attributes for all model classes in this MetaData.cs file as follows:

```
public class AllUsersMetaData
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    [Remote("codelength", "Rules", AdditionalFields = "S1,S2", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NewUserMetaData
{
    [Display(Name = "Document Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create another .cs file for partial classes and write it as per your model as follows:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(AllUsersMetaData))]
public partial class AllUsers
{
}

[MetadataType(typeof(NewUserMetaData))]
public partial class NewUser
{
}
```

Keep both of these files in the same namespace as your EDMX. And name of the classes in partial classes must exactly be same as your model classes generated by EDMX. In this way, when ever you update your model from database, your attributes won't be deleted.